# Landau's Theorem on tournaments

Tags: graph-theory

There is a Landau's theorem related to [tournaments theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_%28graph_theory%29).
Looks like the sequence $(0, 1, 3, 3, 3)$ satisfies all three conditions from the theorem, but it is not possible for 5 people to play tournament in such a way (if there are no ties). Did I miss something?

Comment: Are you sure your question is related to _Mathematica_ (TM) "the software"?

Comment: @belisarius Yes, here is a similar question on the same forum http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145662/sufficient-condition-for-tournament-score-sequences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Player $A$ loses to everyone.

Player $B$ beats player $A$ and loses to everyone else.

Players $C$, $D$, and $E$ beat each other cyclically, like rock-paper-scissors.

Comment: I don't think C,D and E can form a cycle as no ties are allowed and each player plays only once with other. Here is a graph I'm trying to draw, but for the E there is no way to have 3 outbound edges without making a cycle with C or D: http://i49.tinypic.com/es0ls8.jpg

Comment: There is no requirement that the graph be acyclic.

Answer (score 2):

Draw $K_5$, the complete graph on $5$ vertices, and assign directions to just enough edges to give one vertex ($A$ in the picture below) a score (outdegree) of $0$ and another ($B$ in the picture) a score of $1$.

[image]

At this point only the red edges have not been assigned orientations, and it’s clear that there are exactly two ways to orient them to gives vertices $C,D$, and $E$ scores of $3$: they must form a cycle, either $$C\to D\to E\to C$$ or $$C\to E\to E\to C\;.$$ Either works to give a tournament with the score sequence $\langle 0,1,3,3,3\rangle$.